# adaptive http request throttling algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm currently in a spray  based web application backend project. if you don't know what spray is , never mind, just trait it as a back end http request handling system. unfortunately, there is no existing request throttling support with srpay. so I'd like to write my own.

I don't want to use token bucket or similar algorithm, because the capacity of the server is pre-configured. you maybe give a very conservative estimation which far behind the server's real capacity.
so what I'd like to do is let the server actually learning its' own capacity by the feedback of request 
per second, request per second response. request handling per second, and average response time.mainly the four statistics, but not limited to them.

It's adaptive throttling, so the system is dynamically aware the actual request handling capacity. 
Anyone can suggest some existing algorithms or related papers.